# Insert value into column which is named in known column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I'm preparing data for machine learning where data is in pandas DataFrame which looks like this:

```
Column   v1    v2
first    1      2
second   3      4
third    5      6
```

now i want to transform it into:

```
Column  v1  v2  first-v1  first-v2  second-v1  econd-v2  third-v1  third-v2
first   1   2     1        2         Nan        Nan       Nan      Nan
second  3   4     Nan      Nan       3          4         Nan      Nan
third   5   6     Nan      Nan       Nan        Nan       5        6
```

what i've tried is to do something like this:

```
# we know how many values there are but 
# length can be changed into length of [1, 2, 3, ...] values
values = ['v1', 'v2']

# data with description from above is saved in data 
for value in values:
    data[ str(data['Column'] + '-' + value)] = data[ value]
```

Results are a columns with name: 
`['first-v1' 'second-v1'..], ['first-v2' 'second-v2'..]`
where there are correct values. What i'm doing wrong? Is there a more optimal way to do this because my data is big?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with swaping and sorting `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = data.set_index('Column', append=True)[values].unstack()
         .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('-'.join)
print (df)
   first-v1  first-v2  second-v1  second-v2  third-v1  third-v2
0       1.0       2.0        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN        3.0        4.0       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN       5.0       6.0
```

Or [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = data.set_index('Column', append=True).stack().unstack([1,2])
df.columns = df.columns.map('-'.join)
print (df)
   first-v1  first-v2  second-v1  second-v2  third-v1  third-v2
0       1.0       2.0        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN        3.0        4.0       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN       5.0       6.0
```

Last `join` to original:

```
df = data.join(df)
print (df)
   Column  v1  v2  first-v1  first-v2  second-v1  second-v2  third-v1  \
0   first   1   2       1.0       2.0        NaN        NaN       NaN   
1  second   3   4       NaN       NaN        3.0        4.0       NaN   
2   third   5   6       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN       5.0   

   third-v2  
0       NaN  
1       NaN  
2       6.0
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your answer, i would don't figure this out by my self, thanks again!